# how to select rows in a many to many table with multiple filters

Tags: mysql

I have this table (a table with many to many rows):

```
+---------+---------+
| id_user | id_task |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       2 |
|       1 |       3 |
|       3 |       1 |
|       3 |       2 |
|       4 |       2 |
|       4 |       5 |
|       5 |       2 |
|       7 |       3 |
|       7 |       5 |
|      10 |       1 |
|      10 |       4 |
|      10 |       5 |
|      11 |       4 |
|      11 |       5 |
+---------+---------+
```

I need to get only the rows with specific filters. For example, I need only the rows has **3 and 5** id_task **minimum** (if the user has more tasks is fine, but if the user hasn't the minimum required tasks, doesn't work), the response should be:

```
+---------+---------+
| id_user | id_task |
+---------+---------+
|       7 |       3 |
|       7 |       5 |
+---------+---------+
```

Or grouped by id_user, the response should be:

```
+---------+
| id_user |
+---------+
|       7 |
+---------+
```

The simple queries with "AND" & "OR" doesn't work, because get all rows with id_task = 3 and id_task = 5, but I need the records that meet both conditions: users who have tasks 3 and 5 minimum.

PD: The solution will be used on a dinamically filter from HTML form. So the id_tasks will be 2 (3 & 5) or more (2,5,4, etc)

The dump:

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for many_many_table
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `many_many_table`;
CREATE TABLE `many_many_table` (
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_task` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of many_many_table
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `many_many_table` (`id_user`, `id_task`) VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO `many_many_table` (`id_user`, `id_task`) VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO `many_many_table` (`id_user`, `id_task`) VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO `many_many_table` (`id_user`, `id_task`) VALUES (4, 5);
INSERT INTO `many_many_table` (`id_user`, `id_task`) VALUES (5, 2);
INSERT INTO `many_many_table` (`id_user`, `id_task`) VALUES (10, 1);
INSERT INTO `many_many_table` (`id_user`, `id_task`) VALUES (7, 5);
INSERT INTO `many_many_table` (`id_user`, `id_task`) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO `many_many_table` (`id_user`, `id_task`) VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO `many_many_table` (`id_user`, `id_task`) VALUES (10, 4);
INSERT INTO `many_many_table` (`id_user`, `id_task`) VALUES (10, 5);
INSERT INTO `many_many_table` (`id_user`, `id_task`) VALUES (11, 4);
INSERT INTO `many_many_table` (`id_user`, `id_task`) VALUES (7, 3);
INSERT INTO `many_many_table` (`id_user`, `id_task`) VALUES (11, 5);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Do you want to find users having _only_ tasks 3 and 5, and nothing else, or is it OK to also have other tasks provided that 3 and 5 are present?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : I need to find users having minimum the tasks 3 and 5, if the user has more tasks is fine, but if the user hasn't the minimum required tasks, doenst work.

Answer (score 2):

For your exact query, I prefer the following aggregation approach:

```sql
SELECT id_user
FROM many_many_table
WHERE id_task IN (3, 5)
GROUP BY id_user
HAVING MIN(id_task) <> MAX(id_task);
```

A more general form of the above, to which you may add any number of items to the `IN (...)` clause, would be:

```sql
SELECT id_user
FROM many_many_table
WHERE id_task IN (3, 5)  -- add more task IDs here
GROUP BY id_user
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_task) = 2;
```

Comment: it's really a good solution, filtering rows that have tasks either 3 or 5 and then making sure there is at least one row matching for id_task = 3 & id_task = 5 for a user.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : how extend this query when need filter 3 or more items (... IN (3, 4, 5, ...) ...)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:`SELECT * FROM many_many_table WHERE id_user = 7 and (id_task = 3 or id_task = 5)`

Comment: Doesn work, because I don't know the id_user, only the ids of the tasks to filter

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to use inner queries without thinking  much

for getting rows matching criteria:

select * from many_many_table where id_user in (select distinct id_user from many_many_table  as t1 where id_task = 3 and id_user in
(select distinct id_user from many_many_table  as t2 where id_task = 5))

you can use group by on this final result to get group by results

Comment: how extend this query when I need filter 3 or much more filter items: `where id_user in (..subquery (..subquery (..subquery (`

Comment: select * from many_many_table where id_user in (SELECT id_user
    FROM many_many_table
    WHERE id_task IN (3, 5)
    GROUP BY id_user
    HAVING  group_concat(distinct id_task order by id_task) = "3,5")                                                                       use any comma-separated values as you desire in where clause and having clause. In having clause, use sorted order